# smooth swiping between tabs in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, mat-tab

How can I implement smooth swiping between tabs in angular?

I am using mat-tabs (angular material tabs) and want to add tab-swiping support for touch devices (like WhatsApp or Telegram for mobile).

resources I found provide the tabs parent element (mat-tab-group) with a `selectedIndex` input and update it based on the `swipeleft` and `swiperight` events.

My problem with this solution is that the transition is instant and not smooth,
and even if I add some custom animation, the swipe can't be canceled after it's started (in the apps I mentioned above it can.)

So is there a way to achieve this with mat-tabs or is there a different component library I can use for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: did you figured it out?
I have exact same problem. Animation in mat-tab-group exists from the box. However, in mat-tab-nav-bar it completely absent. I need smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `animationDuration` directive to `mat-tab-group` and it will animate the transition between tabs:

```html
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="1000ms">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i assume you didn't understand the question correctly,
i am talking about swiping the tab-body itself, not clicking the tab headers